# TFS support for netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans, ide, tfs

I need to checkout and manage a project from TFS (Team Foundation Server) and was wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

I usually use SVN, but for this particular project, TFS is a requirement.

The best way I've found so far with a bit of Googling is at http://marceloverdijk.blogspot.com/2009/01/grails-netbeans-and-microsoft-team.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer, no I don't think there is any *easy* way to integrate the Netbeans IDE and TFS. However there are some options.

Firstly you could use the [SVN bridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) this allows subversion clients to connect to TFS. If that is viable then you should be good to go. Here are a couple of blog posts that you may find useful when using TFS if you have a SVN background. [SVN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2011/01/18/tfs-guide-for-subversion-users.aspx) to [TFS](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/tfs/explaining_tfs.html). If SVN Bridge doesn't meet your needs then there are other ways to use TFS but none of them are integrated in to the Netbeans IDE.

If you're developing on Windows then you can install [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38) (Use the version that matches the version of TFS you're using e.g. if you're connecting to TFS 2010 then install Team Explorer 2010), this will install a Visual Studio Shell and the Team Explorer plugin. Along side that it will install the "`tf`" command line utility, you then have a choice of using either a GUI with the VS plugin, or the command line.

You should also install the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f), they add some usefull functionality such as extra command line tools (using the "`tfpt`" command) they will also install windows explorer integration, this will allow you to do some basic Source Control functions from the Right Click menu in windows explorer (Check out, check in, diff etc)

[image: Windows Explorer and TFS]

You should also look at [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=af1f5168-c0f7-47c6-be7a-2a83a6c02e57&displaylang=en), I don't think it does Netbeans integration but it does do Eclipse.  If you're developing on an OS other than Windows then this is your only option.

To use any on these tools you must have a TFS CAL to be licenced properly. If you have an MSDN licence that will probably include a CAL, if not then someone needs to spend some cash and buy one :-).

Comment: I see now that the link you provided in the question suggests SVN Bridge, blogspot is blocked by my companies firewall so I couldn't read the blog earlier. This is probably the easiest way of using netbeans and TFS but the blog suggests that they had problems with getting the latest version. This isn't necessarily a problem with SVN Bridge as TFS tries to keep track of the versions of files you have in your workspace. If TFS thinks you have the latest version of a file, it wont bother to download it again when you go a "get". See the links I provided to the blogs for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to go with the SVN Bridge solution.

Answer (score 6):

Since `TFS` started to support `Git` repositories, it is possible to:

1. create `TFS` project for `Git`
2. after project creation use url from `Code` tab
3. to configure `Git Repository Location` in `NetBeans` IDE

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the tf.exe (from Visual Studio or Team Explorer) there is a plugin that can be configured to do the TFS commands from NetBeans:

1. Download plugin from: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=676
2. Install the plugin in NetBeans: Tools\Plugins\Downloaded\Add Plugins…
3. Configure the plugin in NetBeans: Tools\Options\Path Tools
4. At Edit Commands For File enter: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout "{path}"
5. Press Ok
6. With a file selected in the editor, or the package explorer press the “Edit Path…” toolbar button.
7. The file is now checked out in TFS.

Make sure to use the proper path to tf.exe.
There are 3 buttons, so you can configure 3 TFS actions (I use checkout, add, delete).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actively supports only *Eclipse* for TFS integration.

At [this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/578396/netbeans-support-for-team-foundation-server-tfs) there are more info and the possibility to upvote, to report your interest in such a feature directly to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

In NB 8.2 you can setup Kenai Team Server.
then you will be able to login into a team server : menu Team->Team Server -> login